# Using Sqoop, is it possible to perform hive import from an Oracle View instead of table?

Tags: sqoop

Assume I have an Oracle view created by joining few other tables, it is possible to import the view data into Hive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible as it is an object for sqoop and if we can fire a query, we can fetch data via sqoop. This can be also be checked from sqoop eval command and you can try to run to see if view is accessible or not.

```
sqoop eval (generic-args) (eval-args)
```